# Подключение isql по unixODBC

Tags: postgresql, centos, unix-odbc

isql не может подключиться к базе:

```
isql -v callback-connector
[28000][unixODBC]FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

При этом я могу подключиться через psql:

```
psql -U postgres
postgres=# select now();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2016-02-29 04:38:28.882498-05
(1 строка)
```

В pg_hba.conf указано:

```
local   all             all                                     password
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             192.168.1.17/32         trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               password
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
```

Может есть какие предположения, с чем это связано?

Comment: по умолчанию firebird использует пользователя sysdba с паролем masterkey: `isql -u sysdba -p masterkey ...`

Comment: уточните, что это за программа — `isql`. это интерактивный интерфейс к базам данных *firebird* или к базам данных *ms/sqlserver*?

Comment: isql - интерактивный инструмент командной строки unix для работы с DSN. В /etc/odbc.ini прописываются коннекторы к разным базам данных с использованием ODBC драйвера, а isql, да и не только он, используют эти коннекторы для подключения к БД.